# Removing HTML code in R using gsub

Tags: regex, r

I have a portion of HTML code in R like the one below:

```
"</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\"> <a href=\"group.php?g=1\">XXXX</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\"> <a href=\"category.php?c=100050\">YYYY</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\"> <a href=\"category.php?c=100050&brand=Motorola\">ZZZZ</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\">AAAA"
```

I want to use gsub to remove the unwanted HTML code so that the output will be:

```
XXXX YYYY ZZZZ AAAA
```

I tried `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>` as shown [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) but fail, why?

How can I do it in R? Thanks.

Comment: it might be cleaner to extract names from html code using the `XML` library and `xPath` queries. if you post a link to the webpage containing the html code, there are many on SO who would be able to provide you with pointers on how to extract the desired information.

Comment: Be careful...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Should this question and the other be merged?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057374/remove-anything-within-a-pair-of-parenthesis-using-gsub-in-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing html tags from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227294/removing-html-tags-from-a-string-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you heed the warnings of @Ramnath and @Iterator and use a parser instead, but here is the best I can do with your string and `regex`:

(First add a missing  to the end of your input string)

```
x <- "</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\"> <a href=\"group.php?g=1\">XXXX</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\"> <a href=\"category.php?c=100050\">YYYY</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\"> <a href=\"category.php?c=100050&brand=Motorola\">ZZZ</a> <img src=\"images/arrow_orange.gif\" width=\"8\" height=\"12\">AAAA</a>"
```

The code:

```
x1 <- gsub("<([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)(.[^>]*)>([.^<]*)", "\\3", x)
x1
[1] "</a>  XXXX</a>  YYYY</a>  ZZZ</a> AAAA</a>"

gsub("</a>", "", x1)
[1] "  XXXX  YYYY  ZZZ AAAA"
```

Comment: No `perl = TRUE`?  I always feel I'm living dangerously if I don't use that in my R regex functions.

Comment: Sadly I'm not of the perl generation, so I always use `perl=FALSE`.  Personal preference, I imagine...