# Remove anything within a pair of parentheses using gsub in R

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have string like below:

```
<a>b<c>
```

I want to remove both `<a>` and `<c>`, but I can't use `gsub("<.*>","","<a>b<c>")` as this will remove the `b` also.

I asked a similar question before, but on a second thought, I think I should learn in general, how to deal with this kind of problems. Thanks.

Comment: The more general solution is to use a parser.  Unless you can be sure that there are no escaped symbols, that every symbol is matched, that nesting doesn't occur, and many other caveats, it is best to use a parser.  There's a pretty famous question on SO about regular expressions and HTML.  Although you've not mentioned HTML, it looks like you might be headed in the direction of markup languages like HTML and XML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't allow a closing bracket `>` in the stuff between the brackets:

```
z <- "<a>b<c>"
gsub("<[^>]+>","",z)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a non-greedy regex, eg. `/<.*?>/`.

This will only work for simple HTML and can be easily subverted. Consider the following HTML, which cannot easily be removed using regular expressions.

```
<span title="Help > Index">
```

Comment: nope, not ok
    > gsub("/<.*>/","","<a>b<c>")
    [1] "<a>b<c>"

Comment: You have missed a '?' in the regex.

Answer (score 4):

One more idea, often quite useful in noisy settings (i.e. when it comes nearer to making a tokenizer):

```
strsplit("<a>b<c>",split='<|>')[[1]][3]
```